# AWK split string then deliminate it as well

Tags: awk, split, delimiter

Need help with splitting the below.

```
100GB@sdb,100GB@sdc
```

Into this

```
sdb sdc
```

Everything I've tried keeps giving me

```
sdb 100GB
```

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary number of disks, try:

```
$ echo '100GB@sdb,100GB@sdc,10KB@sdd' | awk -F'[@,]' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s ",$i; print ""}'
sdb sdc sdd
```

### Answers for original question

#### Using awk

```
$ echo '100GB@sdb,100GB@sdc' | awk -F'[@,]' '{print $2,$4}'
sdb sdc
```

#### Using sed

```
$ echo '100GB@sdb,100GB@sdc' | sed 's/^[^@]*@//; s/,[^@]*@/ /'
sdb sdc
```

#### Using bash

```
$ s='100GB@sdb,100GB@sdc'; s=${s#*@}; echo ${s/,*@/ }
sdb sdc
```

Comment: The prob I have is I don't know how many disks it will span. There can be anywhere from 1 to 10+ so $2,$4 won't always be the case.

Comment: @debow OPK.  See update for more general case of an arbitrary number of disks.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative AWK command:

```
% awk 'BEGIN{RS="[@,]";ORS=" "}NR%2 == 0' <<< '100GB@sdb,100GB@sdc'
sdb sdc
```

This will split on `@` and `,` and then print all even chunks:

```
100GB@sdb,100GB@sdc
# 1    2    3    4  <- chunk
```